# Ensuring initialization works fine without raising exception

Tags: rspec

I want to let(:variable) an object , so that I can use this object in differents tests across the contexts. However at the same time , I want to ensure that no exceptions were thrown while initalizing the object. Is it possible.

Right now I am doing this within an example. I want to `let` the first var , so that it can be reused across examples.

```
first_object= nil
  expect{first_object= StandaloneG28::Forms::G28.new(attorey_profile,application_manager: appManager)}.to_not raise_exception
  expect{Pdf::AttributeMappings::FillableG28Applicant.new(first_object).export(false)}.to_not raise_exception
  expect{Pdf::AttributeMappings::FillableG28Sponsor.new(first_object).export(false)}.to_not raise_exception
```

The attorney_profile and application_manager is defined in outer context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare the let block and then test it as follows:

```
let(:first_object) { StandaloneG28::Forms::G28.new(attorey_profile,application_manager: appManager)}

it 'should not throw exception' do
  expect{ first_object }.to_not raise_exception
end
```

This works because let doesn't evaluate till it's first called within the scope of an example. Thus, any exceptions raised during initialisation can be evaluated using expect.

Note, that when testing for exceptions/errors you need to use the curly brace for the except declaration otherwise except won't even get a chance to see the exception.

Comment: Smart .. never thought about this though I know about this lazy evaluation and also say  in the question " I want to let". Late nights never help anyone.

Comment: hehe yep... done it myself plenty of times, with the answer staring me in the face... this is where an extra pair of fresh eyes helps :)